# How to declare an associative array with user-defined key?

Tags: typescript, associative-array

My attempt:

```
class Key {
    foo: string = "";
}

var dict = new Map<Key, number>();
dict[new Key()] = 1; // <-- error here
```

I'm getting an error:

> Type 'Key' cannot be used as an index type.

I also thought about using a plain JS "object" (which functions an associative array) but those can only be indexed by strings.

I also tried `Record`:

```
class Key {
    foo: string = "";
}

var dict : Record<Key, number> = {}; // <-- error here
dict[new Key()] = 1;
```

And got:

> Type 'Key' does not satisfy the constraint 'string | number | symbol'.
> Type 'Key' is not assignable to type 'symbol'.

I also tried index signatures:

```
class Key {
    foo: string = "";
}

interface MyDict {
    [index: Key]: number; // <-- error here
}

var dict = new MyDict();
dict[new Key()] = 1;
```

And got:

> An index signature parameter type must be either 'string' or 'number'.

So, how do I declare an associative array with an user-defined key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `Map`, you don't use `theMap[key] = value` (that's for setting object properties), you use the [`set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/set) method:

```
dict.set(new Key(), 1);
```

Similarly, to get a value from the `Map`, you use the [`get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get) method:

```
value = dict.get(someKey);
```